# My computer keeps failing to re-start whenever I try to install SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My computer keeps failing to re-start whenever I try to install SQLServer 2008.

I successfully downloaded the exec file from Microsoft website, and when I run it, it comes up with the following:

> Setup up Support Rules identify problems that might occur when you
>   install SQL Server Setup support files. Failure must be corrected
>   before Setup can continue.

The in a list i shows a green tick for 5 different things and a red cross for "Restart Computer".

Please does anyone understand what is going on here. I really need to install this.

Comment: Does it keep failing to re-start, per your title, or does the SQL Installer keep stating that it needs to re-start, which is what it seems like from the body of your question? If the latter, it's possibly some *other* installer that keeps running, registering restart actions and then failing in some way. SQL Server is asking for a restart not for itself but so that those restart actions get processed before it takes its turn. Impossible to guess what that other installer may be though.

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/78831/rule-restart-computer-failed-when-installing-sql-server-2008#420137

Comment: I'm sure you have good reasons for installing SQL Server 2008 but it is worth highlighting that [mainstream support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/) for the product has ended.  I feel for you.  It can really hard to find help on the [MS website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/955504) for failed installs.  Perhaps the community over on [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) can help?

Answer (score 0):

The next key from `regedit.exe`

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations

should be cleared after you reboot your system. If not, remove it then reboot again.

[Reference.](https://blog.dragonsoft.us/2008/11/08/tip-installing-sql-server-2008-reboot-required-check-fails/)